# class variable undefined only in one specific method

Tags: angular

I'm wrapping chessboardjs and chessjs, two well known chess javascript libraries, into an Angular project. Everything is doing well except a method in my component .ts... this method is called by the external js library when a piece is dragged (as defined in config) and the call works.
My problem is that inside this method 'onDragStart()' I can't use the class variables board and game because they seem to be undefined, even if I initialize and use them in ngOnInit(). Even a call to updateStatus() is refused as if this method couldn't see a single bit of the class. Here's the code of my component:

````
declare var ChessBoard: any;
declare var Chess: any;

@Component( {
    selector: 'app-chessboard',
    templateUrl: './chessboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./chessboard.component.css']
} )
export class ChessboardComponent implements OnInit {

    board: any;
    game: any;

    constructor() { }


    ngOnInit() {
        var config = {
            orientation: 'white',
            draggable: true,
            position: 'start',
            moveSpeed: 'fast',
            snapbackSpeed: 100,
            snapSpeed: 100,
            pieceTheme: 'img/chesspieces/wikipedia/{piece}.png',
            showNotation: false,
            onDragStart: this.onDragStart,
        }

        this.board = new ChessBoard( 'board', config )

        this.game = new Chess();

        console.log('color of g5: ' + this.game.square_color('g5'));

        this.board.move('e2-e4');

        this.updateStatus();

    }


    onDragStart (source, piece, position, orientation) {
        // do not pick up pieces if the game is over
        if (this.game.game_over()) {return false};

        // only pick up pieces for the side to move
        if ((this.game.turn() === 'w' && piece.search(/^b/) !== -1) ||
            (this.game.turn() === 'b' && piece.search(/^w/) !== -1)) {
          return false
        };
        return true;
      }


    updateStatus () {
        var status = ''

        var moveColor = 'White'
        if (this.game.turn() === 'b') {
          moveColor = 'Black'
        }

        // checkmate?
        if (this.game.in_checkmate()) {
          status = 'Game over, ' + moveColor + ' is in checkmate.'
        }

        // draw?
        else if (this.game.in_draw()) {
          status = 'Game over, drawn position'
        }

        // game still on
        else {
          status = moveColor + ' to move'

          // check?
          if (this.game.in_check()) {
            status += ', ' + moveColor + ' is in check'
          }
        }

        console.log(status);
      }

}
```

and the error message I get when I try to drag a piece:

core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'game_over' of undefined
    at Object.onDragStart (chessboard.component.ts:46)
    at I (chessboard-1.0.0.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.D (chessboard-1.0.0.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39679)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:465)

In this case is 'game' being undefined but I get the same result if I try to use 'board'.
The call to the method is correct: source, piece, position, orientation are filled with good values.
Any Idea? I just don't understand it...

Thanks a lot!

Paolo
````

Comment: Can you create small demo on stackblitz.com So I can take a detailed look. My guess is ngOnInit is called before the external dependencies are are loaded.

Comment: Can you show the result of this log - `console.log('color of g5: ' + this.game.square_color('g5'));`

Comment: @alt255: I'm gonna look stackblitz and create a demo but the code is also available  at https://github.com/pbaioni/ChessboardNg, branch Develop, commit "stackoverflow post"

Comment: @Todarmal here's the result of the log : 'color of g5: dark'

Comment: Can you try initializing the game and board in the constructor. Please let me know if the error comes.

Comment: @Todarmal I tried that, same bahaviour...

Comment: @alt255 sorry, giving up trying with stackblitz, can't copy-paste  or drag-n-drop my code nor import from github...

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to find a solution, it was a contexte problem.

The JS library was linked to a callback function by the line

onDragStart: this.onDragStart

but this leaded to a new instance of the component to be used, so everithing was undefined there.

The correct way to implement the callback was this:

onDragStart: this.onDragStart.bind( this ),

and everything is fine :)

Comment: Saved me a lot of time. Thank you very much!